# How can I filter an MVC Telerik Grid using a selected value of a Telerik ComboBox?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, telerik-mvc

I have an **ASP.NET MVC 3** page (**Razor**) that consists of a **Telerik ComboBox** and a **Telerik Grid**. I cannot figure out how to get values from the combo box using **jquery** and then use the value to filter (or rebind) the grid data.

My **Telerik ComboBox** is loaded with ***category_id***, ***category_name***, and I've got it coded so that it filters itself on the fly as I type the category_name until a perfect match is found or I select an item.

Any guidance about the best way to do this, or tips about making jquery easier (**intellisense for jquery**?) would be appreciated.

Here is one code section of jquery code that results in an error, and the page will not load any data. The error message (from firebug) is: $("#Customers").data("tComboBox") is undefined, but I'm doing this exactly as described on the Telerik site, and when I looked at the page source I saw this:

```
 jQuery('#Categories').tComboBox...snipped the  rest
```

Here is my function that fails:

```
 function dataBinding(args) {
   var categoryName = $("#Customers").data("tComboBox").value();
   args.data = $.extend(args.data, { categoryName: categoryName });
}
```

Comment: Probably better posted on the telerik forums since this seems very telerik api specific. Where is the above dataBinding method called from. Are you sure the combo box is initialized a this point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add intellisense for jQuery, read this post for how to do it:

[jQuery Intellisense Setup](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/02/08/jquery-1-4-1-intellisense-with-visual-studio.aspx)

To retrieve the selected value from the Telerik Combo Box do the following:

**View Markup**

```
// Assumed defenition of the combobox
<%= Html.Telerik().DropDownList()
        .Name("DropDownList")
        .BindTo(new SelectList(Model, "ProductID", "ProductName"))
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 200px; float: left; clear:both; margin-bottom: 230px;" })
%>
```

**Client Script**

```
// Will Get Selected Text
$("#DropDownList").data("tDropDownList").text()
// Will Get Selected Value
$("#DropDownList").data("tDropDownList").value()
```

To clarify further "DropDownList" in `$("#DropDownList").data("tDropDownList").text()` is the name assigned to the control in the helper method (`Html.Telerik().DropDownList().Name("DropDownList")`) so you should change the code you posted above to $("**#Customers**").data("**tCustomers**").value() and it should work.

PS:More information on Telerik ASP.NET MVC ComboBox API can be found at [Telerik API](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/combobox/clientsideapi)